# Problems with python method get_service_stats from azure.storage.blob

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm having this problem with get_service_stats method :

azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f6e32d5d240>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Method:

```
 def geo(self):
        
        # Create a logger for the 'azure.storage.blob' SDK
        logger = logging.getLogger('azure.storage.blob')
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        # Configure a console output
        handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        bloba = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(self.access,logging_enable=True)
        acc = bloba.get_service_stats(logging_enable=True)
```

I could use a object (bloba as example) to connect , upload and download in a storage . I setup the storage as GRS ( geo-replication) , but I need to get the status of geo replication ( Live , invalid , etc.. )

Logging:

```
# python3 main.py 
Connected to Storage Account!
Request URL: 'https://rpaivatesting123-secondary.blob.core.windows.net/?restype=service&comp=stats'
Request method: 'GET'
Request headers:
    'Accept': 'application/xml'
    'x-ms-version': '2019-12-12'
    'x-ms-date': 'Wed, 11 Nov 2020 21:09:52 GMT'
    'x-ms-client-request-id': '3d73d876-2462-11eb-a223-7cb27d33114d'
    'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.5.0 Python/3.6.9 (Linux-5.4.0-48-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic)'
    'Authorization': '*****'
Request body:
None
Request URL: 'https://rpaivatesting123-secondary.blob.core.windows.net/?restype=service&comp=stats'
Request method: 'GET'
Request headers:
    'Accept': 'application/xml'
    'x-ms-version': '2019-12-12'
    'x-ms-date': 'Wed, 11 Nov 2020 21:09:52 GMT'
    'x-ms-client-request-id': '3d73d876-2462-11eb-a223-7cb27d33114d'
    'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.5.0 Python/3.6.9 (Linux-5.4.0-48-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic)'
    'Authorization': '*****'
Request body:
None
```

Downgraded the sdk :

```
Request body:
None
Tuple timeout setting is deprecated
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
    health_check.geo()
  File "/root/sarah/DR/devops-toolbox/azure-storage-health-check/scripts/azure_storage_operations.py", line 113, in geo
    acc = bloba.get_service_stats(logging_enable=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/tracing/decorator.py", line 83, in wrapper_use_tracer
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/storage/blob/_blob_service_client.py", line 257, in get_service_stats
    timeout=timeout, use_location=LocationMode.SECONDARY, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/storage/blob/_generated/operations/_service_operations.py", line 229, in get_statistics
    pipeline_response = self._client._pipeline.run(request, stream=False, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 211, in run
    return first_node.send(pipeline_request)  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  [Previous line repeated 5 more times]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/policies/_redirect.py", line 157, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/policies.py", line 543, in send
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/policies.py", line 517, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/storage/blob/_shared/policies.py", line 318, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 71, in send
    response = self.next.send(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/_base.py", line 103, in send
    self._sender.send(request.http_request, **request.context.options),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/azure/core/pipeline/transport/_requests_basic.py", line 284, in send
    raise error
azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f11404867b8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Comment: COuld you please check if you have provided right connection string?

Comment: Yes , because this is one of the methods .. with the same object I connected , uploaded , downloaded and cleaned the storage ... I just commented the others methods to debug this one

Comment: The method is only available when read-access geo-redundant replication is enabled for the storage account. Since your storage account is GRS,  you cannot use the method. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobserviceclient?view=azure-python#get-service-stats---kwargs-

Comment: I'll test later .. if I have a storage LRS will it work ? Basically when it's GRS and I trigger a failover , it'll become LRS

Comment: I think you also cannot run the method. You need to have read permissions at the secondary region, you can run the method. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob-service-stats and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy#read-access-to-data-in-the-secondary-region

Comment: Thank you ! I gave up to use this method , I created a method to process az cli commands so I can get the status of failover

Comment: If you have no other concerns, do you mind if I post my suggestions as an answer?

Comment: Sure , go ahead

Comment: Hi @rafael, I have summarized my suggestion as a solution. Since it is useful to you, could you please accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I summarize my suggestions below.

The method `get_service_stats` in Azure python storage SDK `azure.storage.blob` is only can be called when read-access geo-redundant replication is enabled for the storage account. In other words, we should have read permissions in the secondary region before we call the method. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob-service-stats) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy#read-access-to-data-in-the-secondary-region).